# Typo3 Neos installation

Tags: neoscms

Installation problem Typo3-Neos beta1

While composer is running the project-create, there are a lot of warnings that "class/TYPO3/Flow/Composer/InstallerScripts is not autoloadable -- post installation scripts cannot be called".
At the end there is no setup file in the Web folder.

Is this a problem with the order of composer's loading of files?

Comment: Did you try just going to `http://site/setup` and check if it works? Got the same warnings using composer but everything seemed to work normally. There is not supposed to be a setup file in the Web/ folder.

Comment: @Janus The instructions on their web page for installation and setup indicate that the first step is running setup from the Web folder. So if I have htdocs/Neos after running composer, then I should go to http://localhost/Neos/Web/setup (if I interpret their instruction correctly).

Comment: You should point your DocumentRoot (web root folder) to /path/to/neos/Web. The files in the directory below /Web/ should not be part of the DocumentRoot.

Answer (score 0):

> "This is just a warning during the composer installation because of the loading order of the packages. After it has gotten to the Flow package it will stop. Everything is fine and there’s no need to worry about it." 
>   -- Aske Ertmann, core dev

http://forum.typo3.org/index.php/t/200300/

Answer (score 0):

Ensure `AllowOverride All` and enable module rewrite (e.g. `a2enmod rewrite` on Debian based systems or in `php.ini` uncomment the line beginning with `mod_rewrite` on Arch or others)

Don't forget to restart or reload apache.

Took me ages to figure it out. Recreated entire servers for it.